# applying a patch file created by git-diff

Tags: filenames, patch

I have done a git-diff to generate a patch file:

```
cd
git diff --no-prefix ~/.vim/bundle/vim-latex-suite/ftplugin/latex-suite/compiler.vim  ~/compiler.vim > ~/vimlatex.patch
```

The resulting patch is

```
diff --git home/rudra/.vim/bundle/vim-latex-suite/ftplugin/latex-suite/compiler.vim home/rudra/compiler.vim
index 65cd33a..abfcff7 100644
--- home/rudra/.vim/bundle/vim-latex-suite/ftplugin/latex-suite/compiler.vim
+++ home/rudra/compiler.vim
@@ -434,7 +434,8 @@ function! Tex_ForwardSearchLaTeX()
        else
            " We must be using a generic UNIX viewer
            " syntax is: viewer TARGET_FILE LINE_NUMBER SOURCE_FILE
-
+           let mainfnameRelative = fnameescape(fnamemodify(Tex_GetMainFileName(), ':p:.:r'))
+           let target_file = mainfnameRelative . "." . s:target
            let execString .= join([viewer, target_file, linenr, sourcefile])

        endif
```

I want to apply this patch to `/home/rudra/.vim/bundle/vim-latex-suite/ftplugin/latex-suite/compiler.vim`

But when I am trying to apply the patch, its giving:

```
patch -p0 < vimlatex.patch 
can't find file to patch at input line 5
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git home/rudra/.vim/bundle/vim-latex-suite/ftplugin/latex-suite/compiler.vim home/rudra/compiler.vim
|index 65cd33a..abfcff7 100644
|--- home/rudra/.vim/bundle/vim-latex-suite/ftplugin/latex-suite/compiler.vim
|+++ home/rudra/compiler.vim
--------------------------
File to patch: /home/rudra/.vim/bundle/vim-latex-suite/ftplugin/latex-suite/compiler.vim
patching file /home/rudra/.vim/bundle/vim-latex-suite/ftplugin/latex-suite/compiler.vim
```

The problem is, while it is working fine, I want it to understand which file it should patch, without asking me **File to patch:**

How I can achieve this?

Comment: Note how your patch is missing the starting /. So in order to apply the patch you need to be located in the root directory, or to supplement the appropriate prefix truncation count with `-p`.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure why the / is missing.

Answer (score 3):

By default, `patch` strips paths from the target files, so you can apply your patch using

```
patch < vimlatex.patch
```

(assuming there’s a `compiler.vim` file in the current directory).

Specifying `-p0` instructs it to use all the target path, so it expects to find a file called `home/rudra/compiler.vim` starting from the current directory. The explanation for that is that the command you used to create the patch was transformed before `diff` is run; the command really used to create the patch is recorded as the first line of the patch (basically, `~` becomes `/home/rudra`, and the leading `/` is stripped):

```
diff --git home/rudra/.vim/bundle/vim-latex-suite/ftplugin/latex-suite/compiler.vim home/rudra/compiler.vim
```

As a result, `patch -p0` by default expects to find a file matching `home/rudra/compiler.vim` (the target file) as explained above.

I don’t think there’s a reliable way to produce the kind of patch you’re after, because `patch` explicitly ignores absolute paths. I’d recommend just using plain `diff` with relative paths:

```
cd
diff -u .vim/bundle/vim-latex-suite/ftplugin/latex-suite/compiler.vim  compiler.vim > vimlatex.patch
```

and applying the patch in the appropriate directory.